# htaccess Url rewrite based on a specific character

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Suppose I have a url `www.example.com/&page1`
I want the url to redirect to `www.example. com/getpage.php?redirect=page1`.
How can I achieve the above using htaccess?

Basically I just want to get the word after `&` in the url if `&` exists in the url then I want to send it as a get parameter to getpage.php.

`getpage.php` handles the value in `$_GET['redirect']` and displays the page accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Redirect 301 /&page1 http://www.example.com/getpage.php?redirect=page1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't actually state the URL or rules need to be dynamic since you only give one example. However this should work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^\&(.+)/?$ /getpage.php?redirect=$1 [L]
```

Comment: what do you mean by _Your question doesn't actually state the URL or rules need to be dynamic_ also the above rule gives me 500 Internal Server Error

Answer (score 0):

```
Redirect 301 /&page1 /getpage.php?redirect=page1
```

Please restart apache.